# removing primary key best practice

Tags: sql, oracle, primary-key

I have been given a system which has a table to track changes each week for customer data changes. Each week records are creating for a new file_id number with the customer_id and the associated action_id, which would be an update ‘U’. It has the following primary key.

```
ALTER TABLE t_customer_file
ADD CONSTRAINT CUSTF_PK PRIMARY KEY (file_id, customer_id, action_id);
```

There is now a change needed so that a customer update can appear twice in a week. So the file_id, customer_id and action_id will be the same so the primary key is failing the package to populate this table.

So I just wanted to know what the best practice was to removing and introducing a new primary key or not having a primary key?

At the moment I have dropped the primary key. I then put an index in place of the same fields with the same name. I would create a new primary key with more columns, but there is only 5 more columns in the table and each of them just contains the data of what has been updated. Here is what I performed to get to have duplicate rows and I compiled a view which used the data from `t_customer_file`.

```
alter table t_customer_file
drop constraint CUSTF_PK
drop index;

create index CUSTF_PK on t_customer_file (file_id,customer_id,action_id);

alter view customer_file compile;
```

Any help on best practices in this scenario would be great.

Comment: It sounds like you should create another column, say, `change_date`, which contains the date the change occurred. Then make your primary key `file_id, customer_id, action_id, change_date` If you have two changes a week, currently you don't know which one happened first do you?

Comment: @ElectricLlama: A timestamp might be even better than a date.

Comment: Quite possibly. I'll leave the original poster to ruminate on that.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a new column "id" as primary key and **alter the application logic to accept multiple records for a file_id, customer_id and action_id combination**. Adding the index for file_id,customer_id and action_id is fine. A good advice i got from stackoverflow in the past is that every table should have a primary key which does not represent application data. Therefor adding a new primary key column "id" (whose purpose is to just make a column unique) is ok.

```
alter table t_customer_file add (id number(22) primary key)
```

You can also sort by this new id or you can add a date/timestamp column for this mentioned in the comments above.

Comment: *"Therefor [sic] adding a new primary key column "id" (whose purpose is to just make a column unique) is ok."* Except that it allows duplicate data, which is the very thing a primary key constraint is supposed to prevent.

Comment: I don't agree that it's best practice. Sometimes its kind of lazy because the designer couldn't be bothered working out what the true business key is.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' it depends from the point of view. the combination of "file_id + customer_id + action_id" will not be unique anymore. but they are unique if you append the new "id"-column. but you must alter the application logic so that it expects multiple records with the same "file_id + customer_id + action_id" combination

Comment: The id number is, by definition, meaningless. You can have 117 rows that have identical data, differing *only* in the id number. So how many updates pertain to a given value for file_id? You can't tell. You can tell how many rows have distinct id numbers for a given file_id, but you can't count how many updates pertain to a given file_id, because you can't distinguish one update from another. When your design can't count, you have a problem, not a solution.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' well thats right. In this case the OP must change the application or use an other solution.